# Print Loop results of each iteration

Tags: r, loops, iteration, tm

I am working with CTM for Text Mining and I'm running a loop to define the optimal number of topics, using the following code:

```
best.model <- lapply(seq(2, 60, by = 1), function(k){CTM(dtm_tfidf,k,
              method="VEM", control=control_CTM_VEM, model = NULL)})
best.model.logLik <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(lapply(best.model, logLik)))
best.model.perplex <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(lapply(best.model, perplexity)))
list(best.model.logLik, best.model.perplex)
```

As this takes too long to get any results, is there a way to get the result of each iteration? With this code I'm only getting the results at the end, and if by any chance I decide to stop it, I get nothing.

Comment: Write something to a file for each iteration is probably safest.

Comment: You could use an explicit `for` loop with a print statement in the body of the loop, rather than using `lapply`. with only 59 iterations, concerns about loop overhead don't really apply.

Comment: If your objective is to get the result for say debugging / review purpose then you can think of writing it to a file. Obviously that is not a choice for final code.

Comment: Agree with using a for loop. Then you could store the results of each loop in the next iteration of a list. P.S. the main reason lapply is faster than a loop is because it allocates resources before executing instead of re-sizing the resources every loop. You can manually do this before your loop to make your loop as fast as your lapply. There are tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will try to use a for loop that would be as fast as this, and then write the results of each iteration to a file. I will try to check some tutorials as I'm still getting familiar with R. Previously I was trying to implement my research using SAS Miner but it has limitations, so I had to work with R. It really is a powerful tool.